# How to enable copy-paste from Excel into custom DataGridView?

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, copy-paste

I am trying to solve this good old problem in my own environment, adapted lots of different solutions, still no success.
I have a `User Control`, named `EntryGrid`, that has a `DataGridView`, it's headers and such things are set in the code. Then there is a form that has an `EntryGrid` dropped to it.
I know that excel columns must be prepared to be able to paste all cells into a row, for this I used this solution: [copypaste](http://codesr.thewebflash.com/2014/10/vbnet-copy-paste-in-datagridview.html), except the Copy part. This is how it looks like at my place:

```
Private Sub EntryGrid_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles EntryGrid4.KeyDown, EntryGrid8.KeyDown, EntryGrid16.KeyDown, EntryGrid32.KeyDown
        e.Handled = True
        Dim entryGrid As EntryGrid = sender
        Dim dataGrid As DataGridView = entryGrid.DataGrid
        If (e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.V) Then
           MessageBox.Show("Success")               'for now
        End If
End Sub
```

This is absolutely not working for me. I even set `KeyPreview` to `True` in the form, but nothing happens ever.
Then I tried [this solution](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?706503-RESOLVED-KeyPress-event-on-a-DataGridView-not-firing), mine with any result:

```
Private Sub EntryGrid_EditingControlShowing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles EntryGrid4.EditingControlShowing
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cell_KeyDown
    End Sub

    Private Sub cell_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success")
        End If
    End Sub
```

`EntryGrid4` is the name of the usercontrol on the form, but it hasn't got any `EditingControlShowing` event, only `DataGridView` has, but I cannot use like this: `EntryGrid4.DataGrid.EditingControlShowing`
I created an event in `EntryGrid` (`Public Event EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)`), but anything's changed.
I am able to paste anything from clipboard to a cell, but it had been possible before I started the modifying.
Thanks for any idea!

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is it just pasting a value in a cell which is in edit mode or something else? Please reword the question and make it more clear and remove parts which are not related to the problem. For example if the question is about pasting from clipboard to a cell in edit mode, you should determine how do you want to paste, using a keyboard shortcut or using a menu. Also that is what you are asking, you don't need to describe about user control structure or excel columns and so on. Please keep the question simple and specific.

Comment: The problem is that any of the two attempts work, if you can help in one, please do that. I'd like to use Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessCmdKey` method of your `UserControl` is what you are looking for. Override it and check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and do what you need. For example:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))
    {
        if (dataGridView1.EditingControl != null)
            dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        else if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Clipboard.GetText();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was so useful! I translated to Visual Basic and put the excel row processing code, and it worked. Thank you very much for raising this processCmdKey approach, any other source did not mention it in connection with copypasting from excel into datagridview.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed VB.NET tag. You're welcome :)